# ember.js transitionTo from jquery ui callback

Tags: jquery-ui, ember.js

I am using jquery-ui datepicker to navigate my application between days. The problem is I am calling transtionTo from the view and I am under the impression this is wrong.

Here is the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/arenoir/rjVUN/

```
App.CalendarView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'div',
  didInsertElement: function() {
    var router;
    router = this.get('controller.target.router');
    this.$().datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      onSelect: function(dateText, instance) {
          router.transitionTo('show', {day: dateText}); 
      }
    });
  }   
});
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, but sometimes it is inevitable. 
The suggestion I would make would be to create a method on the router to handle this case.

In your router:

```
calendarParentRoute: Ember.Route.extend({
  url: "/",
  showDate: Ember.Route.transitionTo('show'),
  show: Ember.Route.extend({
    url: ":date",
    connectOutlets: function(router, context){
      // Do stuff
    }
  })
})
```

View:

```
App.CalendarView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'div',
  didInsertElement: function() {
    var router;
    router = this.get('controller.router');
    this.$().datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      onSelect: function(dateText, instance) {
        router.send('showDate', {day: dateText}); 
      }
    });
  }   
});
```